# Blurry white streaks on CRT monitor - what could the cause be?

Tags: display

I have an old CRT monitor that I just tried connecting to my laptop as an additional display. The display itself works, my windows are replicated there, but anywhere there is text, a white blurry streak starts at that point and continues some two inches to the right. The problem seems the same as the one [described in this MajorGeeks thread](http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?t=81423), but there's no resolution given there either.

I tried restarting the laptop, the white streaks still appear even on the BIOS screen and Windows' bootup sequence. I guess that means it's a hardware level issue, but I'm not sure what kind of issue it could be. I'm ready to dive into the circuitry of it and replace a capacitor or a resistor if someone could give me a good starting point to look for trouble.

I'm probably going to give this away to a local school or something anyway, I just wish to give it in a usable condition since their resources are going to be hugely limited.

Comment: Did you degauss it? Oh man, I can't believe I just typed that. THANK YOU.

Comment: Haha. Yes, old memories kicked in and I did degauss it a few times, didn't help at all.

Comment: This is bleed due to a problem with high frequency response.  Likely a capacitor has failed somewhere, but kinda hard to guess where.  Could also be a failed transistor or diode in the "clamping" circuitry.  Ideally you'd want an oscilloscope to debug it.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Thanks for the response. I don't own an oscilloscope though and it [looks like](http://in.tek.com/oscilloscope#cat_basic) a "basic" model starts at around Rs. 35000 (~$650), definitely outside my budget for this work. If that or getting a professional look into it are the only options I might have to give up on this one for now.

Comment: Well, there's the obvious thing of opening up the unit and looking for a cap that is all crusty or appears burned.  *Sometimes* you can detect a shorted cap with an ohmmeter, though it's kinda iffy.  And if a cap failed "open" then you can jumper another one across it (of roughly the same uF rating) to see if it makes a difference.  (Of course the usual cautions apply re working inside a CRT.)